# How to show an alert when user click on the browser back button?

Tags: browser, back-button

I saw this type question in various sites but not yet I got a fine solution for it.I wish to prevent the user from going backward in an facebook application.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following code in your target page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.history.forward();
function disableBack() 
{
window.history.forward();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="disableBack();" onpageshow="if(event.persisted) disableBack();">
```